# Intellij Module dependency . NoClassDefFound Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies

I am using Intellij Idea 12.1.3 In that I have 2 modules.

In one(A) module I added the external jars and write one class which is using that external libraries. And in another module(B) I made a module dependency with the module(A).

When I trying to use the class in module A from Module B. It shows the error `NoClassDefFound Error` for external libraries but when I run that class in Module A it is working fine. How would I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your `Module B` and go open `module settings`. click on `Module` in opening window.

Now you can see a tabular view. select `dependency` and click on (+) button in the right hand corner. Select `jar or libraries`. Then add your `Module A` and cleck `ok`.

Comment: I already added that external library into module A. I created module dependeny for A with module B. my need is i don't want to include the external library to module B which is already added in module A

Comment: You have to add those since those external libraries use in Module 1

Comment: Why? then why we add module dependencies. Could you explain

Comment: In here Module B needs Module A. Similarly Module A needs some external libraries. Then that implies Module B needs Module A and those external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Check the box in `Export` column of parent module's dependencies:

[image]

The child module can now access classes in parent module's jar dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have external modules, check that they added as library module